# MySQL/Python Syntax Error

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I keep getting a error with a SQL query that is written in python.

Here is the code in question:

```
else:
    else_query = "SELECT count(*) FROM PARKING_SPOTS WHERE OCCUPANCY = %s"
    cursor.execute(else_query, (occupancy,)
                   " AND WHERE LOCATION = %s", (location,))
```

Here's the error message:

```
File "exp1", line 116
    " AND WHERE LOCATION = %s", (location,))
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone spot the error ? I've changed things around several times, including containing part of the SQL query in a variable, yet I receive the same error.

Comment: You can have two conditons in a query, but they need to be both behind **one** WHERE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your query is incorrect because you can't have 2 WHERE clauses
- you can only pass one querystring

so make that:

```
    else_query = """SELECT count(*) FROM PARKING_SPOTS WHERE OCCUPANCY = %s
                    AND LOCATION = %s
                 """
    cursor.execute(else_query, (occupancy, location))
```

parameters for the query need to be passed as a tuple